# Clear all Vim variables

Tags: vim

Is there a way to `unlet` all variables defined in the current Vim session? You can reset all settings using `set all&`, but I can't find an equivalent for variables.

I've tried:

```
:let vars = g:
:for var in keys(vars)
:  unlet var
:endfor
```

But when I `:let g:`, all the variables are still around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you really want to do this, you need add the scope (`g:` for global), like that:

```
let vars = g:
for var in keys(vars)
  " exec 'unlet g:'.var
  unlet g:{var}
endfor
```

Comment: Just a tip, you can say `unlet g:{var}`